# How to build/convert existing Android apps into x86 processor using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-x86

silly question, is there a way to convert existing android java apps using NDK to be able to runs on x86 processor?

I am not experienced in C++ language, so is it possible?

This is my build.gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {

        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true

        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
        include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

        // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
        universalApk false
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.opentoko.opentokowaiter"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And my application succesfully run on x86, but it only shows blank page Hello from C++.

What step I should do to make it run exactly like on ARM-based Android?

Or the only way is by creating all C++ class?

This is my first project for x86. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: The C++ files are compiled with help of `CMakeLists.txt`. Usually **cmake** will compile them for ARM and x86. Actually, it did compile the x86 library for you, otherwise your app would crash on x86. Probably this C++ code checks that processor is ARM, and does not cooperate fully with x86.